# Is this the correct way to count based on a multi-part key in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CatastropheRegion table that only has 3 columns. The primary key is a surrogate and is simply an incremental number for the row. The business key is the combination of a `CatastropheNumber` and a `RegionCode`. Will this query properly count any row that may be a duplicate?

```
select CatastropheNumber
       ,RegionCode
       ,count(*)
from [CatastropheRegion]
group by CatastropheNumber, RegionCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I tried it like this and I am getting no results returned - which is what I would expect. I would only expect a result if for some reason Florida was incorrectly double-listed on a single catastrophe. So I just want to make sure it is an accurate "Zero results".

(using ssms 2014)

Thanks!

Comment: Remove that extra comma between 1:st and 2:nd column in the select-list. And add a comma between 2:nd and 3:rd.

Comment: Yeah I didn't have it in the original query. I just added it in on accident when putting it here on stack.

Comment: Based on what you say you need, it will give you the correct result. But to check these kind of cases, you should always be able to have the same tables and some sample data into a test database and to query against it, so that you are convinced and understand how `GROUP BY` works. You could actually add duplicates and test your query.

Comment: @Collatrl Now you also have some `Numberumber` :D which I guess is just `CatastropheNumber`!

Answer (score 3):

> I would only expect a result if for some reason Florida was
>   incorrectly double-listed on a single catastrophe

Your query is correct in this case but I would have a unique index to enforce this

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UX_BusinessKey 
    ON CatastropheRegion (CatastropheNumber, RegionCode)
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I don't think that I have the ability to do that. After doing some research it looks like a unique index is implemented on the table itself and not just in the query. My query is only a data quality check that gets run for regression testing. I'm imagining that there are already some type of business key constraints connecting those fields. (Hopefully)

Comment: Of course a unique index is on the table. It would remove the need for a regression test too